# Sending notification from Django Backend to Flutter application

Tags: django, flutter

I am implementing single device only login using django-rest-framework, but in order to log out the user from previously logged in device i want to send some notification from backend to frontend, in order to achieve this what would be the possible options present for django?

Comment: Are you currently saving any unique device identifier for each user - like IMEI or something

Comment: No, not currently, i am just generating a new token for each login request for user identification and deleting all the previously generated tokens

Comment: Why actively send a message? The next time the user opens the app on the other device, they will get a message that they are logged out, because the first call using the old token will fail. Isn't that enough?

Comment: You can use firebase for sending push notifications